# Seeing the count of books I've uploaded on Google Play Books

Tags: google-play-books

I uploaded hundreds of books to Google Play Books (part of my collection), and just saw that there is a limit of 1000 books. I don't think that I hit it yet, but I want to be sure.

How can I see how many books I've uploaded?

Here is the link to the upload and library link: https://play.google.com/books/uploads